# Почему регулярное выражение `\b[aA]*\b` выделяет пробелы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Не могу понять, почему регулярное выражение которое написано ниже, выделяет пробелы, хотя нужно только любые слова которые состоят из букв, вне зависимости от регистра?

С примером для проверки:

```
\b[aA]*\b

There’ll be no more "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" 
AaAaAaA AaAaAaA
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что "quantifier" `*` в RegEx обозначает **ноль** или более раз. Попробуйте заменить `*` на `+` (**один** или более раз):

```
\b[aA]+\b
```

[Пример на `regex101.com`](https://regex101.com/r/HITB6x/2)

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли